# lectura de columna

Tags: python

Me interesa lo que ha preguntado el usuario MoS:([Lectura de columna y utilización de celdas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244744/lectura-de-columna-y-utilizaci%C3%B3n-de-celdas)).

Y la respuesta es un simple bucle for:

```
for i in range(1, m_row + 1): 
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1) 
    print(cell_obj.value)
```

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  se trata de una respuesta a otra pregunta. @AIV Deberías añadir esta respuesta a la pregunta que indicas para que quede todo en un mismo sitio.